# SQL Server: recursive CTE with dates - types don't match

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Thought about creating a bit of a calendar with recursive CTE on dates. However I get the following error once running it:

> Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "ddmmyyyy" of recursive query "cte_days"

Code:

```
WITH cte_days(n, weekd, ddmmyyyy) AS
(   
    SELECT 
        0, DATENAME(DW, '09-03-1983'), CONVERT(varchar, '09-03-1983', 10)
    UNION ALL   
    SELECT 
        0 + 1, DATENAME(weekday, DATEADD(day, 1, '09-03-1983')), DATEADD(day, 1, '09-03-1983')                      
    FROM 
        cte_days
    WHERE 
        n < 10
)   
SELECT * 
FROM cte_days
```

At that I tried testing data in `ddmmyyyy` column running two SELECTS in the middle and it was returned accurate:

```
0   Saturday    1983-09-03 00:00:00.000
1   Sunday      1983-09-04 00:00:00.000
```

It also worked fine once creating a temp table with date column and sticking both values in there...

So can you help finding a mismatch?

Thank you.

Comment: Tip: You can use [`SQL_Variant_Property`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sql-variant-property-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to display the data type of an expression. Compare `SELECT SQL_Variant_Property( 0, 'BaseType' ), SQL_Variant_Property( DATENAME(DW, '09-03-1983'), 'BaseType' ), SQL_Variant_Property( CONVERT(varchar, '09-03-1983', 10), 'BaseType' )` 
and `SELECT SQL_Variant_Property( 0 + 1, 'BaseType' ), SQL_Variant_Property( DATENAME(weekday, DATEADD(day, 1, '09-03-1983')), 'BaseType' ), SQL_Variant_Property( DATEADD(day, 1, '09-03-1983') , 'BaseType' );`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server is picky about types of strings.  But I would recommend focusing on *dates* in the CTE and doing your conversions afterwards:

```
WITH cte_days(n, dte) AS (
      SELECT 0, CONVERT(date, '19830309')
      UNION ALL
      SELECT n+1, DATEADD(day, 1, dte)
      FROM cte_days
      WHERE n < 10
     )
SELECT n, DATENAME(weekday, dte), CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), dte, 10)
FROM cte_days;
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon, you are very helpful as usual.

Answer (score 3):

*"Thought about creating a bit of a calendar with recursive CTE on dates."* Honestly, I recommend a Tally over an rCTE. An rCTE is actually significantly slower than a Tally. This should be more than enough to get you started:

```
DECLARE @StartDate date = '19830309';

WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP (100) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3) --Add more Cartisian Joins and increase value of TOP to get more rows
SELECT I,
       DATENAME(WEEKDAY,DATEADD(DAY, I, @StartDate)) AS DayName,
       DATEADD(DAY, I, @StartDate) AS DyDate
FROM Tally;
```

Comment: That's a beauty. Thank you Larnu!

Answer (score 0):

Using CAST function instead of CONVERT also helps:

```
WITH cte_days(n, weekd, ddmmyyyy) 
AS (    
 SELECT 0, DATENAME(DW, '09-03-1983'),CAST(CAST('09-03-1983' AS DATE) AS DATETIME)       
        UNION ALL   
 SELECT n+1, DATENAME(weekday, DATEADD(day, 1, '09-03-1983')), DATEADD(day, 1, '09-03-1983')                        
 FROM cte_days                                                                  
    WHERE n < 10                                                                        
)   
SELECT * FROM cte_days
```

Comment: Yeah, and it always says Sunday starting from line 2 :)

Answer (score 0):

Moving your "FROM cte_days WHERE n < 10" outside of your CTE will work.

```
    --Your Code: 
WITH cte_days(n, weekd, ddmmyyyy) AS
(   
    SELECT 
        0, DATENAME(DW, '09-03-1983'), CONVERT(varchar, '09-03-1983', 10)
    UNION ALL   
    SELECT 
        0 + 1, DATENAME(weekday, DATEADD(day, 1, '09-03-1983')), DATEADD(day, 1, '09-03-1983')                      
    FROM 
        cte_days
    WHERE 
        n < 10
)   
SELECT * 
FROM cte_days
```

Working Code:

```
    WITH cte_days(n, weekd, ddmmyyyy) AS
(   
    SELECT 
        0, DATENAME(DW, '09-03-1983'), CONVERT(varchar, '09-03-1983', 10)
    UNION ALL   
    SELECT 
        0 + 1, DATENAME(weekday, DATEADD(day, 1, '09-03-1983')), DATEADD(day, 1, '09-03-1983')                      
)   
SELECT * 
FROM cte_days
    WHERE 
        n < 10
```

Above returns the following results:

```
n   weekd   ddmmyyyy
0   Saturday    1983-09-03 00:00:00.000
1   Sunday  1983-09-04 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Yes, but the idea with that 10 was to make it iterate 10 times so I would get 10 days from the anchor date. With the suggested code I get 2.